# Increase memory available to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

Attempting to increase memory available to Eclipse Luna so updated below entry to *eclipse.ini*:

```
-Xmx1024m
```

eclipse.ini :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-vmargs
-Xmx1024m
-Xms100m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

But Eclipse still registers as 570MB available : 
[image]

How can increase available memory to Eclipse ?

Comment: 'added' is really annoying me as this VM argument already exists and does not need to be added but modified. Could you please paste your *eclipse.ini* configuration?

Comment: @tmarwen question update

Comment: The 507M is just the amount of heap space Eclipse has needed to use so far, it will increase up to your limit if Eclipse needs more memory.